# How to record from mic and save to WAV file in WinCE with Lazarus?

Tags: delphi, audio, windows-mobile, wav, lazarus

I'm using Lazarus to build a WinCE application to be run in a PDA/PocketPC.

I need to record the voice from the PDA internal microphone for about 10 seconds, and save it to a wav file, but could not find any information or working example about how to do this.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend for this using the standard Windows [Waveform API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743834%28v=VS.85%29.aspx1). In Delphi you can do this with the `mmsystem` unit, you will have to verify if this unit is available in Lazarus.
There is a sample project for sound capturing using these functions [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/SoundRecord.aspx). It was done in C++, but the basic ideas should be the same.